# jpa constructor expressions with multiple SELECT NEW statements

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Is there a way to have multiple `SELECT NEW` statements in a `jpql` query (Hibernate)?

This works for me:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.test.project.dto.ItemService(g,s,l,r) "
        +" FROM Item g, Service s, Service l , Service r"
        +" WHERE s.id = g.id" 
        +" AND s.location = l.name"
        +" AND s.serviceType = 'type'"
        +" AND l.serviceType = 'Location'"
        +" AND l.area = r.name" 
        +" AND r.serviceType = 'Region'")
public List<Item> getAllItemsWithServices();
```

I get the expected Result in my `DTO`.

```
@Component
public class ItemServiceDTO{

    private Item item;
    private Service serviceType;
    private Service serviceLocation;
    private Service serviceRegion;

    public ItemServiceDTO(item item, Service serviceType, Service serviceLocation, Service serviceRegion) {
        super();
        this.item = item;
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
        this.serviceLocation = serviceLocation;
        this.serviceRegion = serviceRegion;
    }
```

But what I want is to have a new instance of `Language` with its contructor.

For example like this:

```
 @Query("SELECT NEW com.test.project.dto.ItemService(g,s,l,r), new LanguageDTO()"
            +" FROM Item g, Service s, Service l , Service r"
```

Or in a subselect of `ItemService`

```
 @Query("SELECT NEW com.test.project.dto.ItemService(g,s,l,r, new LanguageDTO())"
                +" FROM Item g, Service s, Service l , Service r"
```

I also interested in using `Map` and `List` in my DTO Objects but I read thats not possible? Is that right?

My Spring boot application does start with errors while using the two examples.

At the end I want a Map of `Map<List<Item>,Map<List<LanguageDTO>,List<ItemServiceDTO>>> map;`

Comment: What's your JPA provider (i.e. EclipseLink, Hibernate)?

Comment: Sorry, its Hibernate

Comment: hello.   I am trying to use the new operator but finding little resources. question:   do you create a jpa repo interface and place this statement: public List<Item> getAllItemsWithServices(); in that that repo?   An example or reference to a complete example would be highly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Technically, by definition of JPQL select clause, it would allow multiple constructor expressions.

> - select_clause ::= SELECT [DISTINCT] select_expression {,    select_expression}*
> - select_expression ::= single_valued_path_expression |    aggregate_expression | identification_variable |
>     OBJECT(identification_variable) | constructor_expression
> - constructor_expression ::= NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {,    constructor_item}* )
> - constructor_item ::= single_valued_path_expression |    aggregate_expression
> - aggregate_expression ::= { AVG | MAX | MIN | SUM } ([DISTINCT]    state_field_path_expression) | COUNT ([DISTINCT]
>     identification_variable | state_field_path_expression |
>     single_valued_association_path_expression)

Example:

```
SELECT NEW com.test.model.UserName(u.firstname, u.lastname), NEW com.test.model.UserEmail(u.email) FROM User u
```

However, I just discovered that Hibernate does not allow it. When I switched JPA provider from Hibernate to EclipseLink, it works. So, you may need to consult with your provider if such query syntax is allowed.

Take note however, that when using NEW operator, your constructor has to have arguments (at least one). So this expression won't work:

```
SELECT NEW LanguageDTO()
```

On your second question, whether it is possible to use `List` and `Map`, I'm quite confused how you would want to use these collections in your query. However, take note that it is not possible to have collection valued path expressions in your SELECT clause as per definition of the JPQL SELECT_CLAUSE.